# Unspecific limits in a summation sign

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a probability problem, displayed in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yz3i.png), in which I encounter a problem. The solution is on the left and the original assignment on the right. The problem is that I don't get the final step in the solutions of part 1 and 2 of 11.1a and 11.b. The summation sign has lower limit l=1 and upper limit l=k-1. Because, as all probabilities for every number k=1,...,N are equal to 1/N, p(k)=1/N, there is no longer any l in the summation sign in which you can fill in the limits.

Anyone who can help me?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yz3i.png)

Comment: Are you asking why $\Sigma_{l=1}^{k-1} (\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{N})=\frac{k-1}{N^2}$?

Comment: Yes, or in the case of part 2 of 11.1a, how do they account for the lower and upper limit in the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the definition of the summation symbol. You probably know
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i:=x_1+x_2\ldots + x_n.$$ Now if $x_i$ is independent of $i$, i.e. $x_i=c$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$ for some constant  $c$, well then $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=\sum_{i=1}^n c=c+c+\ldots+c$ ($n$-times in total), so $\sum_{i=1}^n=nc$.

In words, for some fixed $k\leq n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, "$\sum_{i=k}^n [\text{something}]$" means:

> 1. Start by setting $i=k$ and evaluate $\text[\text{something}]$ for this $i$
> 2. Increase $i$ by one
> 3. Evaluate $\text[\text{something}]$ for $i$ and add it to the previous result
> 4. Repeat 2. & 3. until $i=n$, then stop.

*Remark 1*: So in total you do $n-k+1$ steps (check by counting).

*Remark 2*: If $[\text{something}]$ is independent of $i$, then there's not much to evaluate, you just take the $[\text{something}]$ as it is. Otherwise nothing in the above strategy changes.

This means that $$\sum_{l=k}^n c=c+c+\ldots+c=(n-k+1)c.$$

This means for example in 11.1a where $k$ is fixed:
$$\sum_{l=k-6}^{6}\left(\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)=\sum_{l=k-6}^{6}\frac{1}{36}=(6-(k-6)+1)\frac{1}{36}=\frac{13-k}{36}$$

Answer (score 0):

what ever $a$ is, it holds $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a=\underbrace{a+a+...+a}_{k-1 \text{ times}}=a\cdot(k-1)$